# nc: invalid option -- 'z'

Tags: linux, rhel, netcat

On RHEL 7.2 OS, I get following error when trying to run nc commnad

```
nc -z -v -w1 host port
nc: invalid option -- 'z'
Ncat: Try `--help' or man(1) ncat for more information, usage options and help. QUITTING.
```

Is there any alternative to it

Comment: @fedorqui Presumably not. His question is how to work around the missing option.

Comment: There are a lot of versions of nc/netcat around. In my system I have the Hobbit version with the `-z`, the OpenSSL without it, and the NMap witout it either.

Comment: @fedorqui. It does not show up under man nc

Answer (score 6):

maybe nc is a link to ncat, use the commands to check：

```
which nc | xargs ls -l
```

if the nc is linked to ncat,you should relink nc to netcat, if netcat is not installed, refer the website:http://netcat.sourceforge.net/download.php

Answer (score 5):

It seems the old version of `nc` is being phased out everywhere in favour of [Nmap Ncat](https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/index.html). Unfortunately this doesn't have the rather useful `-z` option.

One way to get equivalent functionality (test whether the target host is listening on a given port) is to transform this:

```
nc -z hostname port
```

Into this:

```
cat /dev/null | nc hostname port
```

You might also want to add in an option like `-w 1s` to avoid the long default timeout.

There might be a cleaner combination of options that avoids the need for the `/dev/null` but I couldn't figure out what.

I've also seen talk of using `tcping` to do the same thing, but that doesn't seem to be available on all distros.

Answer (score 0):

On the newer RHEL 7 nc is a link to ncat, while you may be used to nc on the older RHEL6 and below.
ncat seems not to have the -z option, and being a different project having a look at it's man page is a good idea, or at least examine it's internal help

```
ncat -h
```